# Sys.mkdir not recognized

Tags: ocaml

OCaml doesn't recognize `Sys.mkdir` (despite working `Sys.file_exists` and `Sys.remove`).

`which ocaml` returns `/home/x0000000001/.opam/4.11.1+afl/bin/ocaml`.
Printing `Sys.ocaml_version` returns `4.11.1`.
I am working in a dune project `lang dune 3.6`.

The OCaml [documentation](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Sys.html) :

> val mkdir : string -> int -> unit 
> Create a directory with the given permissions.

It says just above

> Since 4.05

So it should be available ?

Could someone please explain this trickery to me ?

Comment: OCaml 4.11.1 dates back to August 2020. I think you owe it to yourself to upgrade.

Comment: Note that you can link directly to `mkdir` with https://ocaml.org/api/Sys.html#VALmkdir .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Printing `Sys.ocaml_version` returns 4.11.1.

> So [Sys.mkdir] should be available ?

No, as you probably already figured out, the `Since 4.05` deals with a previous function, while the [full documentation of `mkdir`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/96004ee8006be453a658a819ff8c2637411e974c/stdlib/sys.mli#L104-L108) says:

```ml
external mkdir : string -> int -> unit = "caml_sys_mkdir"
(** Create a directory with the given permissions.

    @since 4.12
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The version printed in the documentation corresponds to the command just above (it is not ordered by `Since ...` as I thought). 
Visually not quite clear though.